# PHPExcel lost cell format after setting cell value

Tags: phpexcel

I´m using PHPExcel 1.8.0 to fill a Excel5 file, but:

when I use:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('a1')->setValue("test");
```

A1 cell format is lost, but when I use:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow(0,0)->setValue("test");
```

A1 cell format is preserved as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The only think I can think of is to capitalise the `A` in the cell address `A1`

Comment: Yes @MarkBaker capitalise A worked... thanks a lot ...probably there is a problem with getCell

Comment: Yes, I've been looking at this, and the PHPExcel code probably should force upper-casing internally